# How to insert a character on a terminal, rather than replace?

Tags: c, terminal

I am working on the terminal input functionality in an application that can receive input via terminal. I have canonical mode and echo disabled so all terminal input is truly processed by the program (with some exceptions, like `^C`, etc.). One reason for doing this is input cannot block and by default the kernel buffers input until it gets a new line, and I really need character by character processing.

For the most part, this isn't an issue. I can handle things like backspace correctly. I can even handle escape-sequence characters like the left arrow key by doing this multiple times.

A challenge I have encountered is how to insert characters on the terminal, sort of like using the "INSERT" key (on by default), in a graphical application. I can echo the left arrow sequence back to the terminal to get the cursor to shift left one character on the terminal.

However, if I type a character, it then overwrites the character present there (if one). This isn't unexpected, but I would like to optionally be able to *insert* the character inbetween the two, the same way that any regular "cooked" TTY would do it. I tried sending the "INSERT" key escape sequence to the terminal, followed by echoing the typed key, and this causes all kinds of terminal chaos to break loose. If I type `t`, it minimizes the entire terminal window. Typing `r` moves the cursor to the top of the screen, and `e` does a page down of the cursor.

"Something" is happening here, but this isn't quite what I was looking for.

What escape sequence would I need to send to the TTY in order to have it insert the character, as opposed to replace?

For reference, this is what I'm sending to the TTY for "Insert":

`27`, `91`, `50`.

These are the raw values written out to the terminal output file descriptor using `write`.

If I then send an 'e' to the TTY, that causes the window to minimize (SSH session on Windows).

Some escape sequences, like left arrow, are bidirectional in that sending the left arrow to the server also works if sent to the client, in accomplishing what you'd think it would, but it seems the same may not be true for all of them. Is there any way I can force the next character to be inserted and shift characters down, as opposed to overwriting?

An alternative would be to print `\r` and then rewrite the entire line as it existed so far, but I'm trying to avoid that. Essentially, I'm trying to emulate however a higher-level line editor would do this, but I can't find any details on the escaping for this. [This page has a good example](https://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BuildyourownCommandLinewithANSIescapecodes.html#a-basic-command-line), but it seems to rewrite the entire line.

Comment: On an xterm the `smir` sequence (for 'enter insrt mode') is \E[4h.  You appear to be using \E[2 which is an incomplete escape sequence, so is likely to cause confusion.  See `man 5 terminfo` for the terminal database, and `infocmp` to see what the strings for your current `$TERM` are

Comment: The escape sequence that a key sends is not necessarily the same as the sequence used to control the terminal.

Comment: You would probably be better of using `ncurses`.

Comment: @Barmar As I said, I need 100% control over the terminal, so I have to do it manually

Comment: @ChrisDodd That seems to do it, please post as answer

Comment: @ChrisDodd Also, do you know if the reverse is true: a sequence to "delete" and retract trailing test as opposed to leaving spaces? Both those commands are pretty helpful, but I'm not seeing anything for that there...

Comment: There the `dch`/`dch1` sequence to delete character(s) from a line (will shift the rest of the line back to the left)